# Semantic Issue: Comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have researched online and couldn't find an answer. On Xcode 6 I have a error:

Semantic issue: Comparison between pointer and integer ('UILabel*' and 'int')

The code is (ViewController.m):

```
    -(void)enemyMovement {

enemyShip.center = CGPointMake(enemyShip.center.x, enemyShip.center.y + 2);

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(enemyShip.frame, mothersShip.frame)) {
    lives = lives - 1;
    liveString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LIVES: %i", lives];
    livesLabel.text = liveString;

    //Stop enemy moving
    [enemyMovementTimer invalidate];

    if (livesLabel > 0) {
        [self positionEnemy];
    }



    if ((livesLabel = 0)) {
        [self gameOver];
    }


    }
}


-(void)gameOver {

[enemyMovementTimer invalidate];
[missleMovementTimer invalidate];
[self performSelector:@selector(replayGame) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];



}



- (void)replayGame {

    score = 0;
    lives = 3;

    scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SCORE: 0"];
    liveString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LIVES: 3"];

    scoreLabel.text = scoreString;
    livesLabel.text = liveString;

    startButton.hidden = YES;

    friendlyShip.hidden = NO;
    enemyShip.hidden = NO;
    mothersShip.hidden = NO;

    scoreLabel.hidden = NO;
    livesLabel.hidden = NO;

    [self positionEnemy];

}
```

The error occurs when integer is '1' but when integer is '0' the error doesn't occur and the lives goes into negative numbers, but the command doesn't occur for either number. The command is to revert back to the start of the game. I Think the problem is something to do with the way that the lives label is set out, I also think it might be something about the '=='. But i am not sure completely I have tried to solve this problem, but I have been unsuccessful, several times. I hope you can help me.

Thank You in advance

Comment: FYI - Do not use `=` for equality, its for assignment. Use `==` to compare for equality.

Comment: Please learn C before you attempt to use Objective-C.

Comment: It looks like `livesLabel` is a label.  It doesn't make sense to compare it to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`livesLabel > 0` is comparing the memory address of the `livesLabel` object to the number `0`. What you want is to compare `0` to the text that the label shows. The comparison would look like this: `[livesLabel.text intValue] > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing a label to a number. You might need to relearn some fundamental programming concepts, and I can't help you there, but a `UILabel` has a `text` property which can be parsed into an int with `intValue`.

```
if (livesLabel > 0) {
    [self positionEnemy];
}



if ((livesLabel = 0)) {
    [self gameOver];
}
```

I can't even tell what you're trying to achieve, you should compare `lives` instead, not the label to a number, its like trying to compare a sticker with a number, it makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: 1) You need to show what `livesLabel` is and how you got its value. 2) You can't use `=` to compare an integer value. Use `==`.